# vagrant application changes on atlas

Tags: vagrant

In Atlas (by HashiCorp) where do I view application changes that I pushed with `vagrant push`?

I packaged my Vagrant box, then went to hashicorp atlas vagrant section, created new box and released new box successfully.

I then modified Vagrantfile by enabling push

```
config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  push.app = "dmitrymar/debianbox"
end
```

Then did `vagrant push` and got response:

```
Uploading dmitrymar/debianbox: 381 MB/381 MB
Uploaded dmitrymar/debianbox v1
```

I go to https://atlas.hashicorp.com/dmitrymar/boxes/debianbox and I don't see any application change activity. Please advise